# S_FIFO is not declared

Tags: c, named-pipes

I have write the following code , but the compiler tell me that 'S_FIFO' is not declared , i was think that the problem is that  library that containe 'S_FIFO' is not include , so i have included the last 3 library , but the problem does not solved ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    int fd ; 
    if(mknode("/Desktop/s/test" , S_FIFO | 0666 , 0) == -1) 
        printf("ERROR \n");
    fp = fopen("/Desktop/s/test" , "r");
    char string[80] ;
    fgets(string , 80 ,fp) ; 
    fclose(fp); 
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included the correct library, but spelled the function name and macro names wrong.

It should be `mknod()` function with the macro `S_IFIFO`.